# Make Quarterly Time Series in Julia

Tags: julia

In Julia, we can create a Time Array with the following code:

```
d = [date(1980,1,1):date(2015,1,1)];
t = TimeArray(d,rand(length(d)),["test"])
```

This would give us daily data. What about getting quarterly or yearly time series?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merely use the optional step capability of [**Base.range**](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=range#Base.range) in combination with the type [**Datetime.Period**](https://github.com/quinnj/Datetime.jl/wiki/Datetime-Manual#period-types)

```
julia> [Date(1980,1,1):Month(3):Date(2015,1,1)]
141-element Array{Date{ISOCalendar},1}:
 1980-01-01
 1980-04-01
 1980-07-01
 1980-10-01
 1981-01-01
 1981-04-01
 ...
```

And change the step as necessary

```
julia> [Date(1980,1,1):Year(1):Date(2015,1,1)]
36-element Array{Date{ISOCalendar},1}:
 1980-01-01
 1981-01-01
 1982-01-01
 ...
```

#### 0.3.x vs 0.4.x

In version 0.3.x Dates is available in the package *Dates* which provides the module **Dates**, but in version 0.4.x, module **Dates** is built in. Also (currently) an additional subtle difference is **Year** and **Month** must be accessed as **Dates.Year** and **Dates.Month** in version 0.4.x.

Comment: Thanks - for some reason I had to uppercase it:  `[Date(1980,1,1):Month(3):Date(2015,1,1)]`

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit old, but it's worth adding that there is another time series package called [Temporal](https://github.com/dysonance/Temporal.jl)<sup>*</sup> that has this functionality available.

Here's some example usage:

```
using Temporal, Base.Dates
date_array = collect(today()-Day(365):Day(1):today())
random_walk = cumsum(randn(length(date_array))) + 100.0
```

Construct the time series object (type `TS`). Last argument is for column names, but if not given will autogenerate default column names.

```
ts_data = TS(random_walk, date_array, :RandomWalk)
# Index       RandomWalk
# 2016-08-24  99.8769
# 2016-08-25  99.1643
# 2016-08-26  98.8918
# 2016-08-27  97.7265
# 2016-08-28  97.9675
# 2016-08-29  97.7151
# 2016-08-30  97.0279
# ⋮
# 2017-08-17  81.2998
# 2017-08-18  82.0658
# 2017-08-19  82.1941
# 2017-08-20  81.9021
# 2017-08-21  81.8163
# 2017-08-22  81.5406
# 2017-08-23  81.2229
# 2017-08-24  79.2867
```

Get the last observation of every quarter (similar logic exists for weeks, months, and years using `eow`, `eom`, and `eoy` respectively):

```
eoq(ts_data)  # get the last observation at every quarter
# 4x1 Temporal.TS{Float64,Date}: 2016-09-30 to 2017-06-30
# Index       RandomWalk
# 2016-09-30  88.5629
# 2016-12-31  82.1014
# 2017-03-31  84.9065
# 2017-06-30  92.1997
```

Can also use functions to aggregate data by the same kinds of periods as given above.

```
collapse(ts_data, eoq, fun=mean)  # get the average value every quarter
# 4x1 Temporal.TS{Float64,Date}: 2016-09-30 to 2017-06-30
# Index       RandomWalk
# 2016-09-30  92.5282
# 2016-12-31  86.8291
# 2017-03-31  89.1391
# 2017-06-30  90.3982
```

<sup>*</sup> *(Disclaimer: I'm the package author.)*

Answer (score 1):

Quarterly isn't supported yet, but other time periods such as week, month and year are supported. There is a method called `collapse` that is used to convert a TimeArray to a larger time frame.

```
d = [Date(1980,1,1):Date(2015,1,1)];
t = TimeArray(d,rand(length(d)),["test"])

c = collapse(t, last, period=year)
```

Returns the following

```
36x1 TimeArray{Float64,1} 1980-12-31 to 2015-01-01

             test
1980-12-31 | 0.94
1981-12-31 | 0.37
1982-12-31 | 0.12
1983-12-31 | 0.64
⋮
2012-12-31 | 0.43
2013-12-31 | 0.81
2014-12-31 | 0.88
2015-01-01 | 0.55
```

Also, note that `date` has been deprecated in favor of `Date` as a new updated package now runs the date/time functions underneath.